# Pandas - Cumulative Sum, with resets, using GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of several thousand timeseries.

- Each timeseries is identified by an integer

For each timeseries, there is a unique timestamp, so I can enforce the order.

- For the example below I replace the timestamp with an integer idx

Each timeseries has a state column

- For the example below the state is 0 or 1
- But I calculate that and can use NaN or whatever makes it easier

I need to 'discard' all rows before there have been a certain number of consecutive 1's

- It's 30, but for the example below I'm saying 2, to keep the example concise

So, here's some sample data...

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    'idx':   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'value': [0,1,0,1,1,1,1, 0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
})
```

The results that I want are...

```
desired_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [        1,1,1,     2,2,2,2,2],
    'idx':   [        4,5,6,     2,3,4,5,6],
    'value': [        1,1,1,     1,1,0,1,0],
})
```

What I think I need to calculate is...

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
    'idx':   [0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'value': [0,1,0,1,1,1,1, 0,1,1,1,0,1,0],
   #'consec':[0,1,0,1,2,3,4, 0,1,2,3,0,1,0], -- the cumulative sum of value, but resetting whenever a 0 is encountered
   #'max_c': [0,1,1,1,2,3,4, 0,1,2,3,3,3,3], -- the cumulative max of consec
   #                  ^ ^ ^      ^ ^ ^ ^ ^   -- rows I want to keep, as max_c >= 2
})
```

Then I can just take the rows where `test[ test['max_c'] >= 2 ]`

But, how do I calculate `consec`?

- The cumulative sum of `value`, resetting at 0's, independently by `group`?

---

***EDIT:*** My best attempt, but it feels ridiculously long winded...

```
test['cumsum'] = test.groupby(['group'])['value'].cumsum()

test['reset'] = test['cumsum'][ test.groupby(['group'])['value'].diff() == -1 ]
test['reset'] = test['reset'].fillna(0)

test['reset_cummax'] = test.groupby(['group'])['reset'].cummax()

test['consec'] = test['cumsum'] - test['reset_cummax']

test['c_max'] = test.groupby(['group'])['consec'].cummax()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do the `cumsum` after a `groupby` on the column group and every time the column value is `eq` to 0, you create a new group with `cumsum` as well.

```
test['consec'] = test.groupby(['group', test['value'].eq(0).cumsum()])['value'].cumsum()
test['max_c'] = test.groupby(['group'])['consec'].cummax()
print(test)
    group  idx  value  consec  max_c
0       1    0      0       0      0
1       1    1      1       1      1
2       1    2      0       0      1
3       1    3      1       1      1
4       1    4      1       2      2
5       1    5      1       3      3
6       1    6      1       4      4
7       2    0      0       0      0
8       2    1      1       1      1
9       2    2      1       2      2
10      2    3      1       3      3
11      2    4      0       0      3
12      2    5      1       1      3
13      2    6      0       0      3
```

Comment: It feels like the `test['value'].eq(0).cumsum()` should have its own `.groupby(['group'])`?  Or, am I being overly paranoid, as even if it spans two groups, it won't matter anyway, due to it being part of a `groupby` that already includes `group`?  *(I think this works, Thank You, just shooting some other test data at it)*

Comment: @MatBailie the group will restart for any new value in group as both `group` and `test['value'].eq(0).cumsum()` are in the groupby. So even if a group start with a value of 1, a new group hence a new cumsum will start there :)